# Change with grep|sed inverting the order of parametres

Tags: django, shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to make a bulk change with sed in a directory, from `{{ form|as_bootstrap }}` to `{% bootstrap_form form %}`, but "form" can be any name like "process_form" or "user_form".

I found a grep that list all of them: `grep -r '{{ [a-z_\.]*^\|as_bootstrap }}' ./`

So I'm trying with this grep/sed command but it doesn't work:

`grep -rl '{{ [a-z_\.]*^\|as_bootstrap }}' ./ | xargs sed -Ei s@'{{ \([a-z_\.]*\)^\|as_bootstrap }}'@'{% bootstrap_form \1 %}'@g`

Can you point me to the error in the sed regexp ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to escape `{` and `}` in sed extended mode(`-E`). But you can also use BRE mode to avoid escaping curly brakets:

```
sed 's/{{ \([^|]*\)|as_bootstrap }}/{% bootstrap_form \1 %}/'
```

Comment: It works, thanks! The only correction is `{% bootstrap_form \1 %}` instead of `{% bootstrap_form|\1 %}`

Comment: You're welcome... I edited to correct replacement string.